# xcode wont retain an int?

Tags: xcode, int, retain

I know xcode doesn't retain an int, but my code won't seem to update the number at all from a function.

I have in GameController.h

```
int charMainTouch;
```

and

```
@property (assign) int charMainTouch;
```

and in GameController.m:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
  charMainTouch=1;
  NSLog(@"%d",charMainTouch);
}
```

this stores charMainTouch as 1 ok. But, when I call a function from another class it won't store the int

in GameController.m:

```
-(void) mainChar_touch:(int)touchTrue{ // when an class/object in touched

charMainTouch = touchTrue;//this is=2

NSLog(@"%d",charMainTouch);//this prints out 2

}

-(void) update:(CADisplayLink*)sender {
NSLog(@"%d",charMainTouch);//this still outputs 1 as if the "-(void) mainChar_touch:(int)touchTrue" had no effect on storing the int!

}

-(void)startGame {//this was already called

displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@ selector(update:)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

I don't know why it won't update the int from this function!
I have tried this:

```
 -(void) update:(CADisplayLink*)sender {
charMainTouch = charMainTouch+1;
NSLog(@"%d",charMainTouch);//works! prints out an increasing number

}
```

but when the "-(void) mainChar_touch:(int)touchTrue" is called at any point, it doesn't effect the int at all...! Any ideas why?

The function, altho called from outside is still within the class so shouldn't it update the int? I've tried everything.

Comment: Yes, I have @synthesize charMainTouch; here. It seems to be classing charMainTouch as a different int and not storing it when the function is called from another UIView

Comment: funny ... just tested this and it works for me ...?!
btw, if you use charMainTouch directly you could abandon the @property/@synthesize because you access the ivar directly.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two or more instances of this class? Can you post the code that actually calls mainChar_touch:

Comment: thanks pkyeck, ive removed the @property and syth (still not working but good tip). The code that calls mainChar_Touch is a UIView called CharMain.m

Comment: `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 
 
 
 //UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
 
 //self.center = [touch locationInView:[self superview]];
 gameController = [[GameController alloc] init];
 [gameController mainChar_touch:1];
 
 mainCharTouch_start = self.center;
 
 
}`

Comment: is it something to do with where the `gameController = [[GameController alloc] init];` is in the CharMain.m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're creating a totally new game controller in your touchesBegan:withEvent: method.

And then you're setting a property on the new game controller instance, not the instance you may have had already.

Comment: Ah ofcourse! Im an amature at this, so the 'gameController = [[GameController alloc] init];' is createing a totally new instance?? I have tried without this and it doesnt connect to the GameController, how do I connect?

Comment: Ive now got this working, thanks for your help! I removed 'gameController = [[GameController alloc] init];', but also when creating charMain in the GameController, i should of set 'charMain.gameController = self;' (gameController was set in CharMain as the outlet)

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a property and synthesising it, you probably want to use the setters and getters that are synthesised unless you have a reason not to. 
i.e.

```
[self setCharMainTouch:1];
```

or

```
self.charMainTouch=1;
```